# PDF of distance from origin to simplex in high dimension

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, simplex

Let $\Delta^{n-1}$ be the standard simplex in $n$ dimensions:

$$ \Delta^{n-1} = \{ \mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n: \sum_i x_i=1 , \mathbf{x}\geq0\} $$

And assuming that we are uniformly sampling points $\mathbf{X}$ from this simplex, then the Euclidean distance $|\mathbf{X}|$ can also be considered a random variable. In the limit of $n\rightarrow\infty$, does the probability distribution of $|\mathbf{X}|$ approach some limit distribution that can be written in closed form?

Comment: As a first step, can you derive the expectation? Variance? Even possibly (an approximation of?) the MGF/CF?

Comment: Why did you accept the currently accepted answer when it only provides a computation for $\mathbb{E}[\lVert X\rVert_2^2]$? You asked for much more than that...

Comment: Notice that you always have lower-bound  $\|X\| \ge 1/\sqrt{n}$ a.s. Indeed, $\|X\| \ge \mbox{dist}(0,\Delta_n) = \inf_{x \in \Delta_n} \|x\| \ge 1/\sqrt{n}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's change a bit the symbols and define
$$
\eqalign{
  & T(n - 1,c) = \left\{ {{\bf x} \in R^{\,n} \;:\;\sum\limits_{1\, \le k\, \le \,n} {x_{\,k} }  = c\quad \left| {\;0 \le x_{\,k} } \right.} \right\}  \cr 
  & U(n,c) = \left\{ {{\bf x} \in R^{\,n} \;:\;\sum\limits_{1\, \le k\, \le \,n} {x_{\,k} }  \le c\quad \left| {\;0 \le x_{\,k} } \right.} \right\} \cr} 
$$

Let's then introduce a second euclidean reference system $\bf y$, 
having the $y_n$ axis aligned with the diagonal axis $x_1=x_2=\cdots = x_n$, normal to $T(n-1,c)$
$$
{\bf y} \in R^{\,n} \;:\;{\bf y} = {\bf Q}\,{\bf x}\; \wedge y_{\,n}  = {1 \over {\sqrt n }}\sum\limits_{1\, \le k\, \le \,n} {x_{\,k} } 
$$
The matrix $Q$ being orthogonal.

Indicating by $V(n,\, c)$ the volume of $U(n,\, c)$, and by $A(n-1,\, c)$ the volume of $T(n-1,\, c)$, we know that
$V(n,\, c)=c^n/n!$ and that the relation with $A(n-1,\, c)$ is given by
$$
\eqalign{
  & V(n,c) = {{c^{\,n} } \over {n!}} =   \cr 
  &  = \mathop {\int { \cdots \int {} } }\limits_{{\bf x}\, \in \,U(n,\,c)} dx_{\,1}  \cdots dx_{\,n}
  = \mathop {\int { \cdots \int {} } }\limits_{{\bf y}\, \in \,U(n,\,c)} dy_{\,1}  \cdots dy_{\,n}  =   \cr 
  &  = \int_{t = 0}^{\;c} {\left( {\mathop {\int { \cdots \int {} } }\limits_{{\bf x}\, \in \,T(n - 1,\,t)} dy_{\,1}  \cdots dy_{\,n - 1} } \right){{dt} \over {\sqrt n }}}  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {\sqrt n }}\int_{t = 0}^{\;c} {A\left( {n - 1,t} \right)dt}  \cr} 
$$
so that
$$
\eqalign{
  & A\left( {n - 1,c} \right) = \sqrt n {{c^{\,n - 1} } \over {\left( {n - 1} \right)!}}\quad \left| {\;A\left( {1,c} \right) = \sqrt 2 \,c} \right.  \cr 
  & V\left( {n,c} \right) = \int_{t = 0}^{\;c} {V\left( {n - 1,t} \right)dt}  = {{c^{\,n} } \over {n!}}  \cr 
  & {{A\left( {n,c} \right)} \over {\sqrt {n + 1} }} = \int_{t = 0}^{\;c} {{{A\left( {n - 1,t} \right)} \over {\sqrt n }}dt}  = {{c^{\,n} } \over {n!}} \cr} 
$$

Coming to the problem, we are practically asked to determine the 2nd moments of T(n-1,1) wrt the origin.
Let's start and determine the moments of U(n,c):
$$
\eqalign{
  & Y(n,c) = \mathop {\int { \cdots \int {} } }\limits_{{\bf x}\, \in \,U(n,\,c)} \left( {\sum\limits_{1\, \le k\, \le \,n} {x_{\,k} ^2 } } \right)dx_{\,1}  \cdots dx_{\,n}  =   \cr 
  &  = \mathop {\int { \cdots \int {} } }\limits_{{\bf y}\, \in \,U(n,\,c)} \left( {\sum\limits_{1\, \le k\, \le \,n} {y_{\,k} ^2 } } \right)dy_{\,1}  \cdots dy_{\,n}  =   \cr 
  &  = \int_{t = 0\;}^{\;c} {\left( {\mathop {\int { \cdots \int {} } }\limits_{{\bf y}\, \in \,T(n - 1,\,t)} \left( {\sum\limits_{1\, \le k\, \le \,n} {y_{\,k} ^2 } } \right)
 dy_{\,1}  \cdots dy_{\,n - 1} } \right){{dt} \over {\sqrt n }}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \int_{t = 0}^{\;c} {\left( {\mathop {\int { \cdots \int {} } }\limits_{{\bf x}\, \in \,T(n - 1,\,t)} \left( {\sum\limits_{1\, \le k\, \le \,n} {x_{\,k} ^2 } } \right)
 dA\left( {n - 1,t} \right)} \right){{dt} \over {\sqrt n }}}  \cr} 
$$

Then
$$
\sqrt n {d \over {dc}}Y(n,c) 
 = \mathop {\int { \cdots \int {} } }\limits_{{\bf x}\, \in \,T(n - 1,\,c)} \left( {\sum\limits_{1\, \le k\, \le \,n} {x_{\,k} ^2 } } \right)
dA\left( {n - 1,c} \right)
  = I(n - 1,c)
$$
and 
$$
{{I(n - 1,1)} \over {A(n - 1,1)}}
$$
will give the required expected value of the sum.

Let's put up a recursion to compute $Y(n,c)$.
$$
\eqalign{
  & Y(n,c) = \mathop {\int { \cdots \int {} } }\limits_{{\bf x}\, \in \,U(n,\,c)} \left( {\sum\limits_{1\, \le k\, \le \,n} {x_{\,k} ^2 } } \right)dx_{\,1}  \cdots dx_{\,n}  =   \cr 
  &  = \int_{x_{\,n}  = 0}^{\;c} {\left( {\mathop {\int { \cdots \int {} } }\limits_{{\bf x}\, \in \,U(n - 1,\,c - x_{\,n} )}
 \left( {\left( {\sum\limits_{1\, \le k\, \le \,n - 1} {x_{\,k} ^2 } } \right) + x_{\,n} ^2 } \right)dx_{\,1}  \cdots dx_{\,n - 1} } \right)dx_{\,n} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \int_{t = 0}^{\;c} {t^{\,2} \left( {\mathop {\int { \cdots \int {} } }\limits_{{\bf x}\, \in \,U(n - 1,\,c - t)} dx_{\,1}  \cdots dx_{\,n - 1} } \right)dt}  +   \cr 
  &  + \int_{t = 0}^{\;c} {\left( {\mathop {\int { \cdots \int {} } }\limits_{{\bf x}\, \in \,U(n - 1,\,c - t)}
 \left( {\left( {\sum\limits_{1\, \le k\, \le \,n - 1} {x_{\,k} ^2 } } \right)} \right)dx_{\,1}  \cdots dx_{\,n - 1} } \right)dt}  =   \cr 
  &  = \int_{t = 0}^{\;c} {t\,^2 \;V(n - 1,\,c - t)dt}  + \int_{t = 0}^{\;c} {Y\left( {n - 1,\,c - t} \right)dt}  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {\left( {n - 1} \right)!}}\int_{t = 0}^{\;c} {t^{\,2} \;\left( {c - t} \right)^{\,n - 1} dt}  + \int_{t = 0}^{\;c} {Y\left( {n - 1,\,c - t} \right)dt}  =   \cr 
  &  = {{c^{\,n + 2} } \over {\left( {n - 1} \right)!}}\int_{s = 0}^{\;1} {s^{\,2} \;\left( {1 - s} \right)^{\,n - 1} ds}  + \int_{s = 0}^{\;c} {Y\left( {n - 1,\,s} \right)ds}  =   \cr 
  &  = {{c^{\,n + 2} } \over {\left( {n - 1} \right)!}}{\rm B}(3,n) + \int_{s = 0}^{\;c} {Y\left( {n - 1,\,s} \right)ds}  =   \cr 
  &  = {{2c^{\,n + 2} } \over {\left( {n + 2} \right)!}} + \int_{s = 0}^{\;c} {Y\left( {n - 1,\,s} \right)ds}  \cr} 
$$

The first two values for $Y$ are
$$
\eqalign{
  & Y(1,c) = \int\limits_{0\, \le \,x\, \le \,c} {x^2 dx}  = {{c^{\,3} } \over 3}  \cr 
  & Y(2,c) = \int\!\!\!\int\limits_{0\, \le \,x + y\, \le \,c} {\left( {x^2  + y^2 } \right)dxdy}  =   \cr 
  &  = \int_{y = 0}^c {\left( {\int_{x = 0}^{c - y} {\left( {x^2  + y^2 } \right)dx} } \right)dy}  =   \cr 
  &  = \int_{y = 0}^c {\left( {\left( {{{\left( {c - y} \right)^3 } \over 3} + y^2 \left( {c - y} \right)} \right)} \right)dy}  =   \cr 
  &  = {{c^4 } \over {12}} + {{c^4 } \over 3} - {{c^4 } \over 4} = {{c^4 } \over 6} =   \cr 
  &  = {{2c^{\,4} } \over {4!}} + \int_{s = 0}^{\;c} {{{s^{\,3} } \over 3}ds}  \cr} 
$$

The recurrence can be solved to give
$$
Y(n,c) = {{2n} \over {\left( {n + 2} \right)!}}c^{\,n + 2} 
$$

and finally
$$
{{I(n - 1,c)} \over {A(n - 1,c)}} = {{\sqrt n {d \over {dc}}Y(n,c)} \over {\sqrt n {{c^{\,n - 1} } \over {\left( {n - 1} \right)!}}}} = {2 \over {\left( {n + 1} \right)}}c^{\,2} 
$$

i.e., in your notation
$$
E\left[ {\left| {\,{\bf X}\,} \right|^{\,2} } \right] = {2 \over {n + 1}}
$$

Now,  the PDF of each point is given by $dA(n-1,1)/A(n-1,1)$.
$dA(n-1,1)$ can be conveniently expressed in terms of the $y$ coordinates, but the bounds of $T(n-1,1)$ in terms
of $0 \le x_k$ are not simply convertible into $y$.

For the case of $ f( \bf X)= |\bf X |$, we have better and  use *cylindrical* coordinates around the diagonal axis, according
to the following sketch

[image: Dist_Simplex_1]

We can deduce that the PDF of $ x= |\, \bf X \, |$ will be
 - null till $x$ reaches the distance of $T(n-1,1)$ from the origin: $d=1/ \sqrt{n}$;
 - after that we will have that $x=\sqrt{d^2+r^2}$, where $r$ is the radius of a $(n-2)$-sphere, lying in the plane of $T(n-1,1)$ and centered with it;
 - while $r$  increases from $0$ to the in-radius $R_I = 1/\sqrt{n(n-1)}$ the corresponding sphere remains inside the simplex, with a surface area of
$$
S(n - 2) = {{2\pi ^{\,\,(n - 1)/2} } \over {\Gamma \left( {(n - 1)/2} \right)}}r^{\,n - 2} 
$$
 - after $r$ has surpassed the in-radius, the sphere it individuates will partly debord out of the simplex, 
the circle in red in the sketch; the section of its area intercepted by the simplex will be that inside the solid angles defined by the vertices;
 - the intercepted area will become  null at the circum-radius $R_C = \sqrt{(n-1)/n}$.

The problem is that for high $n$, the volume gets concentrated on the border of the sphere.
 This makes so that the maximum of $PDF(r)$ moves beyond the in-radius and it becomes fundamental to express
the area intercepted by the vertices.
I could not yet succeed in that, and could not find on the web a simple formulation .

**--- 2nd step  ---**

Let's summarize our knowledge till here and introduce $J(n-1,c)$ as the sum of the 2nd moments of $T(n-1,c)$ wrt its centroid.
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  d\left( {n,c} \right) = {c \over {\sqrt n }} \hfill \cr 
  A\left( {n - 1,c} \right) = \sqrt n {{c^{\,n - 1} } \over {\left( {n - 1} \right)!}} \hfill \cr 
  Y(n,c) = {{2n} \over {\left( {n + 2} \right)!}}c^{\,n + 2}  \hfill \cr 
  I(n - 1,c) = \sqrt n {d \over {dc}}Y(n,c) = {{2n\sqrt n } \over {\left( {n + 1} \right)!}}c^{\,n + 1}  =  \hfill \cr 
   = A\left( {n - 1,c} \right)d\left( {n,c} \right)^{\,2}  + J(n - 1,c) \hfill \cr 
  J(n - 1,c) = I(n - 1,c) - A\left( {n - 1,c} \right)d\left( {n,c} \right)^{\,2}  =  \hfill \cr 
   = {{\left( {n - 1} \right)\sqrt n } \over {\left( {n + 1} \right)!}}c^{\,n + 1}  \hfill \cr 
  S(n - 2,r) = {{2\pi ^{\,\,(n - 1)/2} } \over {\Gamma \left( {(n - 1)/2} \right)}}r^{\,n - 2}  \hfill \cr 
  R_{\,I} (n - 1,c) = {c \over {\sqrt {n\left( {n - 1} \right)} }} \hfill \cr 
  R_{\,C} (n - 1,c) = {c \over {\sqrt {n/\left( {n - 1} \right)} }} \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

Clearly we can write, in "polar coordinates", that
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  J(n - 1,c) = {{\left( {n - 1} \right)\sqrt n } \over {\left( {n + 1} \right)!}}c^{\,n + 1}  =  \hfill \cr 
   = \int_{r\, = \;0\;}^{\;R_{\,I} } {r^{\,2} \;S(n - 2,r)dr}  + \int_{r\, = \;R_{\,I} \;}^{\;R_{\,C} } {r^{\,2} \;S_{\,P} (n - 2,r)dr}  \hfill \cr 
  A\left( {n - 1,c} \right) = \sqrt n {{c^{\,n - 1} } \over {\left( {n - 1} \right)!}} =  \hfill \cr 
   = \int_{r\, = \;0\;}^{\;R_{\,I} } {S(n - 2,r)dr}  + \int_{r\, = \;R_{\,I} \;}^{\;R_{\,C} } {S_{\,P} (n - 2,r)dr}  \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
where $S_{\,P} (n - 2,r)$ is the surface of the sphere included in the simplex.

Using the duplication formula for Gamma 
$$
\Gamma \left( n \right) = {{2^{\,n - 1} } \over {\sqrt \pi  }}\Gamma \left( {n/2} \right)\Gamma \left( {n/2 + 1/2} \right)
$$

we reach then to
$$
\eqalign{
  & \int_{r\, = \;\;R_{\,I} (n - 1,\,c)\;}^{\;R_{\,C} (n - 1,\,c)} {S_{\,P} (n - 2,r)dr}  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {{{n^{\,1/2} } \over {\Gamma \left( n \right)}} - {{2\pi ^{\,\,(n - 1)/2} } \over {n^{\,\,(n - 1)/2} \left( {n - 1} \right)^{\,\,(n + 1)/2} \Gamma \left( {(n - 1)/2} \right)}}} \right)c^{\,n - 1}  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {1 - {{2^{\,n - 1} \;\pi ^{\,\,n/2 - 1} \;\Gamma \left( {n/2} \right)} \over {n^{\,\,n/2} \left( {n - 1} \right)^{\,\,(n - 1)/2} }}} \right)A\left( {n - 1,c} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \eta (n - 1)\;A\left( {n - 1,c} \right) \cr} 
$$

So, using in case also the formula for $J$, the problem comes to determine $\eta (n-1,r)$ knowing its integral
from $R_I$ to $R_C$.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for such a detailed answer! I went over it briefly, and it looks correct. Do you think the pdf will converge in law to a normal distribution in the limit of large $n$?

Comment: @PeaBrane: glad it helps. I find the subject very interesting and worthy to deepen.

Comment: @PeaBrane: However I realize now that you are looking for $|X|$ and not for $|X|^2$ : don't know why I went for that (?). Unfortunately introducing $\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+ \cdots}$ will make the situation complicated ..

Comment: This is nice, but why has it been accepted as an answer? It only yields $\mathbb{E}[\lVert X\rVert^2]$, doesn't it? The question was asking for much more than the expectation.

Comment: @ClementC.: yours is an acceptable critics; however (as far as I know) accepting can always be shifted to a better answer. So please provide your contribution on this interesting subject.

Comment: I have to attribute the bounty, so doing it to this answer (only option), but I'd like to see the question fully resolved one day :)

Comment: @ClementC.: thanks for the appreciation. I answered at the best of my knowledge, but the solid angles of a n-simplex represent at the moment an obstacle beyond my capabilities. But it is an interesting subject and I'll keep trying to find a key for it.

Comment: @ClementC. : I could make a step forward ...

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to get the expected value $\mathbb{E}[\lVert X\rVert^2]$, without relying on the Dirichlet distribution (what we are considering here being a spacial case of it, the [symmetric Dirichlet distribution with $\alpha=1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Special_cases)). *This is only computing this expectation, **not** addressing the full question).*

It is well-known that sampling $X$ uniformly from the probability simplex is equivalent to sampling $n-1$ i.i.d. uniform r.v.'s $U_1,\dots, U_{n-1}$, sorting them (adding $U_0=0$ and $U_n=1$), and looking at the differences. From this, we get that $X_1$ is distributed as $\min(U_1,U_2,\dots,U_{n-1})$ , from which its pdf is easily seen to be
$$
f(x) = (n-1)(1-x)^{n-2}, \qquad x\in[0,1]
$$

But we have, by symmetry and linearity,
$$
\mathbb{E}[\lVert X\rVert^2] = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[X_i^2] = n \mathbb{E}[X_1^2] 
$$
from which
$$
\mathbb{E}[\lVert X\rVert^2] = n \int_0^1  (n-1)x^2(1-x)^{n-2} dx = \boxed{\frac{2}{n+1}}
$$

Comment: Is there a way to show that the $X$ components become independent random variables in the large $n$ limit? This seems to be what the following paper claims in the third to last paragraph on page 2: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.4043.pdf

Comment: @PeaBrane They claim this becomes "like independent exponential r.v.'s in the limit" but I am not sure what the basis of their approximation is, nor how quantitative it is.

Comment: I think I've found the answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#Gamma_distribution

Comment: But this is not really helpful either if your goal is to analyze that thing, instead of just sampling, @Peabrane. Handling that denominator (the normalization) is the key issue.

Comment: I guess the argument is that in the large $n$ limit, the relative variance of the denominator is not important.